# Redirecting domain without WWW to the same with WWW

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I'm trying to redirect a domain without WWW to the same domain with WWW at the same path with Apache.

So my .htaccess is:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain\.com\.ar$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.com.ar/$1 [R=301,L]
```

But the redirection, for example, by requesting "http://mydomain.com.ar/myimage.jpg" results on this URL: "http://www.mydomain.com.ar/mydomain.com.ar/myimage.jpg".

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:** Sorry, but was my problem, I am pointing domain in cPanel to the subdirectory public_html/mydomain.com.ar (public_html is also accessible), using the same .htaccess but in that subdirectory actually works.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /    
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.[a-z-]+\.com.ar [NC]
    RewriteRule (.*)$ http://www.mydomain.com.ar/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

I have employed something similar for many years.

Comment: The RewriteBase line is all that is needed to fix the problem.